# Make `coc-python` and `jedi` autocomplete modules installed in a virtual environment

Tags: pygame, python-module, python-venv, neovim, coc.nvim

With the usual `coc.nvim` + `coc-python` + `jedi` setup NeoVim should use system Python modules to run its own plug-ins but Jedi should be able to autocomplete Python modules installed in the active virtual environment. How do I set it up?

I've globally installed NeoVim and `pip install`-ed Pylint and Jedi. I've installed `coc.nvim` and `coc-python` in NeoVim without issues. I have the system Python 3 path in `~/.vimrc`:

```
let g:python3_host_prog = '/bin/python'
```

and the following in `~/coc-settings.json`:

```json
"python.pythonPath": "/bin/python",
"python.jediEnabled": true,
"python.jediPath": "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages",
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
"python.linting.pylintPath": "/bin/pylint",
"python.linting.flake8Enabled": false
```

When I create a virtual environment, activate it, install `pygame` and then run NeoVim in it:

```sh
➜  python3 -m venv myenv && myenv/bin/activate
➜  pip install pygame
➜  nvim
```

both linter and Python 3 provider work fine. Jedi, however, completes members for local code but doesn't complete `pygame`'s members unless I install `pygame` outside of the virtual environment as well, i.e.:

```sh
➜  deactivate
➜  pip install pygame
➜  myenv/bin/activate
➜  nvim
```

But having to install every Python module twice beats the purpose of using virtual environment.

Comment: I don't get why this got a -1. All of the tags exist here. I describe the issue, I describe what I've tried, there's no similar question on stack and no answer to suggested questions solves my issue. How come it's considered a bad question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. In `coc-settings.json`:

```json
"python.pythonPath": "python",
```

NeoVim has to always use `/bin/python` but the path passed to Jedi has to point to Python 3 in the virtual environment when it is active and to `/bin/python` when it isn't. Setting CoC's Python path to just `python` lets `env` take care of it:

```sh
➜  myenv/bin/activate
➜  which python
/home/test/foobar/myenv/bin/python
➜  deactivate
➜  which python
/bin/python
```